# R failing to read identical values as identical

Tags: r

I'm trying to combine two datasets into one using one common column which contains identical values only one of the datasets has duplicated rows. I have tried using merge, left_join and inner_join but R seems to be unable to read some of the values as identical.

Example:

Dataset #1

```
df1:                   
id   month
1    oct
2    dec
3    oct
```

Dataset #2

```
id   color
1    blue
1    red
1    yellow
2    red
3    yellow
3    blue
4    orange
```

And the result that I want would be like this

```
dfboth:
id   color    month
1    blue     oct
1    red      oct
1    yellow   oct
2    red      dec
3    yellow   oct
3    blue     oct
4    orange   NA
```

but R always gives me something as the following

```
dfboth:
id   color    month
1    blue     NA
1    red      NA
1    yellow   NA
2    red      dec
3    yellow   oct
3    blue     oct
4    orange   NA
```

I have tried using

```
dfboth <- merge(df2, df1, by.x="id", by.y="id", all.x = TRUE)
```

and

```
dfboth <- left_join(df2, df1, by="id")
```

I have also tried to change the type of the columns (numeric, integer, character) but that only changes the "id's" that R can't read as identical.

I am somewhat of a beginner in "R" and have no idea what could be the problem so I would appreciate any ideas that you have.

Thanks

Comment: Edit into the text of your question the results of running `dput` on both data frames that you want to combine.

Comment: you could also show us what `str(df1)` and `str(df2)` looks like. Maybe the ids are actually factors...

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate your issue.  Even setting id column in df2 to integer, string and factor it was able to match, so you'll need to provide a put of your tables as others have said.

Answer (score 1):

Works just fine with `left_join()` from dplyr:

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "id   month
1    oct
2    dec
3    oct", header = TRUE)

df2 <- read.table(text = "id   color
1    blue
1    red
1    yellow
2    red
3    yellow
3    blue
4    orange", header = TRUE)

library(dplyr)

dfboth <- left_join(df2, df1)
dfboth
#   id  color month
# 1  1   blue   oct
# 2  1    red   oct
# 3  1 yellow   oct
# 4  2    red   dec
# 5  3 yellow   oct
# 6  3   blue   oct
# 7  4 orange  <NA>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this will do the trick:

```
df1=tibble(id=c(1,2,3),month=c("oct","dec","oct"))
df2=tibble(id=c(1,1,1,2,3,3,4),color=c("blue","red","yellow","red","yellow","blue","orange"))
x0=(sapply(1:nrow(df2),function(x) which(df1$id==df2$id[x])))
x0<-sapply(x0,function(x) ifelse(length(x)>0,x,NA))
x01<-sapply(x0,length)
x01<-ifelse(x01>0,x01,NA)
df2$month<-sapply(x0,function(x) df1$month[x])
> df2
# A tibble: 7 x 3
     id color  month
  <dbl> <chr>  <chr>
1  1.00 blue   oct  
2  1.00 red    oct  
3  1.00 yellow oct  
4  2.00 red    dec  
5  3.00 yellow oct  
6  3.00 blue   oct  
7  4.00 orange NA
```